# Researching background on life in Finland before immigrating to Canada?

Tags: 20th-century, birth-records, canada, finland

My mother arrived from Finland at the port of Quebec on June 2, 1923 at 23 years old. She resided for 19 years before passing away in Sault Ste Marie, Ontario. I would like to research her life in Finland through baptism, school, employment or other documents. I have access to persons in Finland for translation, document search, etc.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take our 2-minute [Tour] that introduces you to the site, which works quite differently to any bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites that you may have tried.  We try to ask one question at a time, and I think your first question should probably be asking how to find her immigration record.  If you already have that, then there is an [edit] button beneath your question that you can use to tell us what it says about where in Finland she came from.

Comment: Hello, welcome to G&FH.SE!  Even though you have narrowed down the time frame to a very tight window, this question is a bit broad -- entire books could be written on how to get started researching the life of an immigrant in the old country.  As it stands you may only get very general answers. If you'd like to narrow the focus of your question, you can use the edit button as PolyGeo suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess: was your mother Anna Korttilalli (Kortti) who married Henry Selin in 1924? And that her parents were Jaakko Korttilalli and Anna Mikkola? If so then she was Anna Kreeta Korttilalli, born in Ii on July 17, 1899. It seems that this Geni profile is about Anna: https://www.geni.com/people/Anna-Selin/6000000032393226242. Maybe the manager of that profile can provide more information or further contacts. The baptism record is available online at the pay site sukuhistoria.fi. You could contact the parish for further information contained in the church records.

It might help a bit that Korttilalli is quite a rare name - there are currently only 20 people in Finland having that name. Maybe your contacts in Finland might be able to find her relatives.

Answer (score 1):

For generic help with Finnish genealogy a good starting point may be [FamilySearch.org](https://familysearch.org/wiki/en/Finland_Genealogy):

> Guide to Finland ancestry, family history, and genealogy: birth
>   records, marriage records, death records, census records, family
>   history, and military records.

Alternatively, we currently have just a few Q&As here tagged [finland](/questions/tagged/finland) that are worth reviewing for specific ideas.